# Does not save data to documents direction

Tags: ios, swift

I try to save data into document directory. I do not get any error but it never saves the data. Always it says "File does not exist, create it".

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default

if let documentsDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last {

   let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("example")

   if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.absoluteString) {
      print("File exists")
   } else {
     print("File does not exist, create it")

     do {
     try myData.write(to: fileURL)
     print("data saved")
     } catch {
       print(error)
     }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.absoluteString) {
```

with

```
if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
```

Never use `absoluteString` in a file system URL